# itkQuadEdgeMesh.dll is not found while building ManagedITK-src-3.20.0.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, itk

I am trying to build ManagedITK-src-3.20.0.0 in VS2010 v4.0 version.to build this.

I have to build InsightToolkit-3.20.1 and my build succeeded so I can use its build in ManagedITK-src-3.20.0.0.while building ManagedITK-src-3.20.0.0 but I am getting this error:

```
"Error  1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ITKQuadEdgeMesh.lib'   D:\ManagedITK2\mBuild\Source\LINK   ManagedITK.Common"
```

I followed every step given to build these projects. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a file called `ITKQuadEdgeMesh.lib`. Or at least the linker can't find it.

Comment: @Axalo I know that I am missing that file,but why?  Am I missing something while building the ITK project?